# Set a persistent environment variable from cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, cmd

I have to set environment variables on different windows machines, but I don't want to be bothered changing them manually by getting on the properties screen of "My Computer"

I want to do it from the command line, with a batch file. As far as I understand, using set will only change the variable for the processes I will call in the command window.

I want to set it definitely, so later, when running a new process, it will use those new settings I have set. Is there a way to do that from the command line?

Comment: Whats the point of setting them from the command line if they are going permanent? You wont need to do it again.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it on several computers, so running the script will save me some time.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can set your env on one computer and do an export of the entries described below and have a .reg file, if SETX isnt available to you.

Comment: RE:  'Whats the point of setting them from the command line...' Where I work there is a constant requirement to a number of persistent environmental variables to different values in order to test/develop different versions of the software. Licensing means it can't be done any other way (e.g. running a VM) so our only resort is to use SETX in a batch script. Using .reg is less good as its harder to document/see exactly what's going on

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Use the [SETX command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28WS.10%29.aspx) (note the 'x' suffix) to set variables that persist after the cmd window has been closed.

For example, to set an env var "foo" with value of "bar":

```
setx foo bar /m
```

Though it's worth reading the 'notes' that are displayed if you print the usage (`setx /?`), in particular:

> 2. On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool will be available in future command windows but **not in the current CMD.exe command window**.
> 3. On a remote system, variables created or modified by this tool will be available **at the next logon session**.

In PowerShell, the [[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) command.

Comment: It seems like SETX is only available on windows XP SP2

Comment: It worked on Windows 7 for me. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @jules: You can get it from the Resource Kit, then.

Comment: Take care with SETX, it truncate your variable length to 1024 char... very dangerous when manipulating %path%.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Just note it's different with PowerShell.

Comment: with Power Shell you can just `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', "Whatever you need it to be", "Machine")`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VikDavid, How to remove?

Comment: @Pacerier You can set it to blank with SETX, not remove though. For more,  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1053944/)

Comment: Use `/M` to make it a system variable

Comment: You need to run the command as administrator

Answer (score 25):

The [MSDN documentation for environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells you what to do:

> To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment** registry key, then broadcast a **WM_SETTINGCHANGE** message with lParam set to the string "Environment". This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

You will of course need admin rights to do this.  I know of no way to broadcast a windows message from Windows batch so you'll need to write a small program to do this.

Comment: Ok, so considering your solution, I have created a registry (.reg) file containing the environment variables I want to add/change. I'll then run this file on all the target PCs. I don't really need to send a windows message, as I will just restart the application that will be impacted. Thanks.

Comment: I'm adding your other answer here, as it was exactly what I was looking for when I stumbled upon this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19705691/3543437

Comment: @David, So why not `setx` per below?

Comment: I think this reg has the advantage of not truncating and not being powershell

Comment: I found a powershell snippet that is said to perform the refresh for exactly this use case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622384/2699217

Answer (score 6):

```
:: Sets environment variables for both the current `cmd` window 
::   and/or other applications going forward.
:: I call this file keyz.cmd to be able to just type `keyz` at the prompt 
::   after changes because the word `keys` is already taken in Windows.

@echo off

:: set for the current window
set APCA_API_KEY_ID=key_id
set APCA_API_SECRET_KEY=secret_key
set APCA_API_BASE_URL=https://paper-api.alpaca.markets

:: setx also for other windows and processes going forward
setx APCA_API_KEY_ID     %APCA_API_KEY_ID%
setx APCA_API_SECRET_KEY %APCA_API_SECRET_KEY%
setx APCA_API_BASE_URL   %APCA_API_BASE_URL%

:: Displaying what was just set.
set apca

:: Or for copy/paste manually ...
:: setx APCA_API_KEY_ID     'key_id'
:: setx APCA_API_SECRET_KEY 'secret_key'
:: setx APCA_API_BASE_URL   'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets'
```

Comment: This so vastly simplified my algorithm work efficiency and saved so much time I thought I'd share it case it might help someone (of those capable of comprehending it)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed SET TEST_VARIABLE=value works for current process only, so `SETX` is required. A quick example for permanently storing an environment variable at user level.

1. **In cmd, `SETX TEST_VARIABLE etc`.** Not applied yet (`echo %TEST_VARIABLE%` shows `%TEST_VARIABLE%`,
2. Quick check: open cmd, `echo %TEST_VARIABLE%` shows `etc`.
3. GUI check: System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> User variables for  -> you should see Varible TEST_VARIABLE with value `etc`.

Answer (score 1):

An example with [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) (.vbs)

````vb
Sub sety(wsh, action, typey, vary, value)
  Dim wu
  Set wu = wsh.Environment(typey)
  wui = wu.Item(vary)
  Select Case action
    Case "ls"
      WScript.Echo wui
    Case "del"
      On Error Resume Next
      wu.remove(vary)
      On Error Goto 0
    Case "set"
      wu.Item(vary) = value
    Case "add"
      If wui = "" Then
        wu.Item(vary) = value
      ElseIf InStr(UCase(";" & wui & ";"), UCase(";" & value & ";")) = 0 Then
        wu.Item(vary) = value & ";" & wui
      End If
    Case Else
      WScript.Echo "Bad action"
  End Select
End Sub

Dim wsh, args
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Select Case WScript.Arguments.Length
  Case 3
    value = ""
  Case 4
    value = args(3)
  Case Else
    WScript.Echo "Arguments - 0: ls,del,set,add; 1: user,system, 2: variable; 3: value"
    value = "```"
End Select
If Not value = "```" Then
  ' 0: ls,del,set,add; 1: user,system, 2: variable; 3: value
  sety wsh, args(0), args(1), UCase(args(2)), value
End If
````

Comment: You should consider adding some context or an explanation to accompany your code.

Comment: Powerful piece of code +1. Works on XP without `setx` (and without possibility to install it). Simple use (in my case): `wsh.Environment("user").Item("myVar") = "my value"`

Comment: Since no one has taken the trouble, to use on XP (no Resource Kit or setx required), to accomplish {set foo=bar} for all (other) DOS windows:
1. save above code as SetVar.vbs
2. setvar.vbs set system foo "bar"
Note, the *current* DOS window does not get FOO from this. Issue
set foo=bar
to achieve that

Comment: Note also, this survives reboot (when you use the system parm)

Answer (score 1):

**Permanently save environment variable using CMD**

For system variable:

> setx variable-name variable-value /m

For user variable:

> setx variable-name variable-value

Note : using /m will save variable in system, without /m will save in user

Comment: This answer was effectively already given **12 years** before you posted here.