# How to set environment variable Path using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to set path environment variable for `MySql`.

I don't get an error, but my code doesn't work.

**Code:**

First:

```
string pathvar = @";C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\\";
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathvar);
```

Second:

```
string pathvar = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathvar + @";C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\\");
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Tru to change `@";C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\\"` to `@";C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\"`

Comment: while using @ no need to set "\" as "\\" , @ before string will result no char, on string that follows, to act as a special char.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are associating the environment variable with your program, but instead you want to associate it with your local machine in order to make it available to every program. Look at the overload that takes an `EnvironmentVariableTarget`.

```cs
var name = "PATH";
var scope = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine; // or User
var oldValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, scope);
var newValue  = oldValue + @";C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\\";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, newValue, scope);
```

Comment: Indeed. EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine; is probably what the he needs.

Comment: You're right. I thought that %PATH% is defined per-user, but apparently it's not.

Comment: @StevenLiekens `PATH` is defined *both* per-user *and* per-machine. The effective `PATH` is the concatenation of both. Which to modify depends on the specific case.

Comment: Copy-pasting this code may result in a **BUG**: GetEnvironmentVariable returns the concatenated path of user and machine, if you do not specify a target. This code would get the total, concatinated path, add something to it, and write it to the machine target. This would duplicate the user path onto the machine path!

Comment: Good eye @Whosdatdev, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Calling SetEnvironmentVariable has no effect on the system environment variables. 
Check this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705691/1057667