# How to create a new command line registered command?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building an app with Unity3d that I want to create a new command line:

`myNewCommand -flag=argument`

The `myNewCommand` will be a shorthand to my application's path. I need a new custom command since I will know the app's path only during installation.

How do I create a new command line for cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the app path to the environment variable "PATH" upon installation

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do that?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094028/9748260