# How can I call Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable without losing the %PathVariableName% such as %SystemRoot%

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, path-variables

Thanks to the posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705401/how-to-set-system-environment-variable-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093715/how-to-set-environment-variable-path-using-c-sharp/22094028), I am able to get the PATH env variable and modify it as I please.

However, once I call `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, scope)`, the returned string no longer has the PATH variable with `%PathVariableName%` (such as `%SystemDrive%`).

Instead of expected `%SystemDrive%\folder`, I get `C:\folder`.

While it functions as intended, I prefer to retain the variables if I can.

Is there any way to keep those path variable name when I call GetEnvironmentVariable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845159/920069

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I am debating if I should close my question as it asks specific question on top of simple Environment Variable change. I will answer my own question and I will let community decide if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RetiredNinja, answer was found in [here answered by Nathan Bedford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845159/1076116).

Basically the path is available in registry, so retrieving the string from there is going to allow me to keep the path variable.

```
string keyName = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\";
string existingPathFolderVariable = (string)Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName).GetValue("PATH", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
```