# What is the equivalent of setenv in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, environment-variables, setenv

I am trying to find an equivalent for `setenv` to use in a C program. What I am trying to do is to modify the values of all the environment variables of the currently running process. I am trying to use `putenv` but it doesn't change the variables` values in any way. What could I do?

Comment: _putenv changes the variables in the process state.  A process obviously cannot change the caller's state.

Comment: *"I am trying to use putenv"* - code, as a proper [mcve], that exhibits what you're trying to do, and shows how it seems to fail specific to your claim, should be added to your question.

Comment: The thing is that I know that the code works, but only in Linux, and I am looking for an alternative in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the correct methods for setting the environment variables. The issue you are hitting is that [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable) which is what is used by the C Runtime `setenv` does not change system-wide environment variables; only the environment of the currently running process.

Changing the system-wide or per-user environment variables on Windows is normally done using scripts or UI. To modify the system-wide environment variables from a C program, you need (a) to run it with [administrator rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=msvc-170), (b) you need to modify the [System Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705401/how-to-set-system-environment-variable-in-c), and (c) you need to send a `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` Win32 message to get the changes picked up by the Windows shell.

Comment: And what if I wanted to change only the currently running process, with something other than setenv?

Comment: As the first link posted in the answer.