# Setting ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME on cmd

Tags: java, batch-file, ant, cmd, java-home

I have batch scripts  , the problem is when I run setup.bat   it sets  JAVA_HOME , ANT_HOME temporarily then I can run build.bat. If I run build.bat only ant calls  gives error. Any idea what is going on here ?

```
Setup.bat 

@echo off
REM ----- BUFFER SIZE-------
mode con:cols=140 lines=9999
REM ------ Change Directory For Java Home ----- 
set PATH=%BASEPATH%
set ANT_HOME=d:\Tools\apache-ant-1.9.4
set JAVA_HOME=d:\Tools\jdk7x64\jdk1.7.0_55
set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;D:\Tools\scripts;%PATH%

Build.bat

REM ----- Drive Selection ------
cd /d "D:\"
cd D:\Work\parser\trunk
call ant -f  build.xml clean devbuild 
cd D:\Work\dm\v3.2 
call ant -f build.xml clean devbuild
```

Comment: Why do you want to run build.bat without setting up the environment properly from setup.bat first?

Comment: yeah it works in that way , but I want  set HOMEs once and remain like that ! I don't want to run setup.bat all the time.

Comment: That's what Environment Variables are for - it sounds like you haven't got Ant or Java setup properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7?rq=1 for more details on how to do that

Comment: I dont want to set Environment Variables  using GUI , I want to set it using cmd thats what I am asking , I know how to set EV from GUI.

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898131/set-a-persistent-environment-variable-from-cmd-exe

Comment: in that page there is solution but that what does hen broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE  in that case ?

Comment: I would use the highest voted answer on that particular question rather than the accepted answer (i.e. using the SETX command if you can).