# set proper environment path variables for Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, path

How to set proper environment path variable for the visual studio in windows

like VSINSTALLDIR, VCINSTALLDIR ,ETC

I will add my own answer as I struggled with this a lot, others are also welcomed to make this answer better.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling and getting lots of errors while setting proper path variables for Visual Studio on Windows.

People use this directly VCINSTALLDIR, VSINSTALLDIR, many newcomers like me face problems so I thought to add this here.

SET INCLUDE

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\extern\include;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\extern\include;
```

SET LIB

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\lib\win64;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\lib\win64;
```

Others are also welcome to add to it.

[image]

My path contains this

```
%MS_VS17%\Community\;
%MS_VS17%\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin;
%MS_VS17%\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;
%MS_VS17%\Community\Common7\IDE;%MS_VS17%\Community\Common7\Tools;
%MS_VS17%\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build;
%MS_VS17%\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64;
%MS_VS17%\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x86;
```

[image]