# Setting environment changes?

Tags: cmd, windows-7-x64, environment, setting

I would like to ask you if it's normal that my "Setting environment" changes after each system reboot or even if I just close my cmd console.

for example, I'm using python 3.5, when I wan to use `python` or to uses `pip` under the cmd I got an error like :

```
C:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To fix this, I use :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python35
```

It works after, but as I said before, once I restart my computer, or I close the console, I've the same problem !!!

Thanks in advance for your help and comments. I just would like to inform you that I'm using `Windows 7 - 64bits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to add this path in System (Windows+Pause key), Advanced, Environment variables. There you have two sections, System and User, in System, edit the PATH key.
The next time you start a console the path will be present.

Alternaly, if you don't want to modify the setting there (or you have no rights) you could start the app with a batch file which sets the path before launching the app.

In Ruby you can adapt the environment variables from within the script itself by using ENV eg `ENV['path'] += 'C:\\Python35'`
, I'm sure Python can do this too but wouldn't know how. In your use case this won't help of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, actually I completely forget to add the path to the system section.

Comment: It's something the python installer should take care of, at least in a MS Windows philosophy.
You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The SETX command will set the variable permanently. Use `SETX /?` for information. [Set a persistent environment variable from cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898131/set-a-persistent-environment-variable-from-cmd-exe)

For Python, many developers use venv which is included with the Python install. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=venv#module-venv