# How to set windows environment variable In tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am working on a Tcl script in which I have a variable and I just want to keep its value alive after the completion of its execution, so I am trying to define a windows environment variable by executing the set windows command within the script using the exec function.

I have also tried to find the solution through google but that too didn't work.
Here is the line of code which I have tried

```
exec set verName=$xVar
```

It would be great if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `set env(YOUR_VARIABLE) value` will set the environmental variable and it is available only during the execution. i.e. It is temporary, not a permanent.

Answer (score 2):

First, read this question and its accepted answer:
[Set a persistent environment variable from cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898131/set-a-persistent-environment-variable-from-cmd-exe)

How do you do that from Tcl? Well, the standard `registry` package gives you the tools:

```
package require registry

set root {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment}
set theVariable "ABCDE"
set theValue "12345XYZ"

registry set $root\\$theVariable $theValue
registry broadcast "Environment"
```

The manual page for the `registry` package has a specific example for using this with the `PATH`. Updating to other variables is trivial. The script will need to be run in a session with Administrator privileges in order to update that part of the registry.

Comment: This won't affect the calling process, though. Unless it is Explorer.

Comment: @Joey That depends on whether the process listens for the `WM_SETTINGSCHANGED` event and acts on it right.

Comment: indeed, but to a first approximation Explorer is about the only process that does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch {exec cmd /C "setX $variable_name $valueToSet"}
```