# Setting environment variables via Command Prompt from file

Tags: windows, environment-variables, command-prompt

Aside from setting N environment variables using these steps:

1. Open **System Properties**
2. Click **Advanced system settings**
3. Click **Environment Variables**
4. Create/Update/Delete Environment Variables

Is there a way to set multiple environment variables on a text file and load it on command prompt? The file would look like this:

```
SET <VariableName>=<PATH>
SET <VariableName>=<PATH>
SET <VariableName>=<PATH>
SET <VariableName>=<PATH>
SET <VariableName>=<PATH>
```

If so, what command should I run if the file would be saved as *EnvironmentVariables.txt*

Comment: You can use `.bat` file (Windows Batch Files) and run them by double-clicking them.

Comment: @sameerkn would this require admin access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a persistent environment variable from cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898131/set-a-persistent-environment-variable-from-cmd-exe)