# raise KeyError(key) from None

Tags: python, environment-variables, keyerror

I am getting an error message and have no idea how to proceed, the error message is displayed below. I have downloaded all necessary tools for it to run however it seems to be having a problem with the keys. I have inputted them right however to keep my account private I have substituted the account username and password hidden. Thanks in advance

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\real-time-intrinio-python-master\real-time-intrinio-python-master> python realtime.py AAPL 
Using Ticker: AAPL 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "realtime.py", line 18, in <module>
     r=requests.get(auth_url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(os.environ['myUsername'] + ":" + os.environ['myPassword'])}) 
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
     raise KeyError(key) from None 
KeyError: 'myUsername'
```

This is the code I am using and line 18 is "r=requests.get(auth_url, headers..."

```
import websocket
import _thread
import time
import requests
import base64
import json
import sys
import os
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

try:
    print ("Using Ticker: " + str(sys.argv[1]))
except:
    print ("Please include ticker as first argument")
    sys.exit()

auth_url = "https://realtime.intrinio.com/auth";
r=requests.get(auth_url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(os.environ['7641353c8540cd7c795c96f097185c26'] + ":" + os.environ['c15d32295cf254ab57d5523c5bf95f80'])})

socket_target = "wss://realtime.intrinio.com/socket/websocket?token=%s" % (r.text)

def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
        result = json.loads(message)
        print (result["payload"])
    except:
        print (message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print ("###ERROR### " + error)

def on_close(ws):
    print ("###CONNECTION CLOSED###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        security = "iex:securities:" + str(sys.argv[1]).upper()
        message = json.dumps({"topic": security,"event": "phx_join","payload": {},"ref": "1"})
        ws.send(message)
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket_target, on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: basically it's saying the environment variables in the OS assigned to `'myUsername'` or `'myPassword'` have not yet been set. On `cmd` terminal, try `echo %myUsername%` and `echo %myPassword%`

Comment: To correct the error @downshift pointed out, at the `cmd` prompt you will need to `set myUsername=something` (and/or `set myPassword=somethingelse`) which will set them temporarily. To set them permanently on Windows, you can define the environment variable(s) and their values is the Settings | Control Panel | System | Advanced system settings, where there's an "Environment Variables..." button.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Sorry, but I'm a complete beginner to python and setting environment variables. I would like to set this variable permanently, so do I need to set as a 'user variables for user' or 'system variables'. Also  do I just simply add new and type myUsername as variable name and "32rqwefrwaf33f" as variable value. Or does a seperate document need to be made.

Comment: I've got it working no worries thanks

Answer (score 1):

*To summarize and add to the conversation.*

As chickity already pointed out, you need to set your environment variables. This can be down with Python or via CMD/terminal.

```py
# Set environment variables
os.environ['myUsername'] = 'username'
os.environ['myPassword'] = 'secret'
```

However, doing this in a script can lead to the potential fatal mistake that your secrets/passwords are added to git. Therefore, it is advised to do this via CMD. To permanently add the environment variables use `setx`. For some more details and caveats see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898197/10093070).

```
setx myUsername username
setx myPassword secret
```

After doing this, you could change line 18 to:

```py
# Get environment variables and create request
USER = os.getenv('myUsername')
PASSWORD = os.environ.get('myPassword')
token = base64.b64encode(f"{USER}:{PASSWORD}")
r=requests.get(auth_url, headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {token}"})
```