# Creating Env variable

Tags: go

At my Windows 11 machine, trying to check if the env variable "" exists or no, if yes, I need to read its value, if not there I need to set it, so I wrote the below code:

```golang
    tmpDir, exists := os.LookupEnv("keyTemp")
    fmt.Println("keyTemp: ", exists)
    fmt.Println("tmpDir: ", tmpDir)
    if !exists {
        tmpDir = os.TempDir() + "\\fitz"
        fmt.Println("tmpDir: ", tmpDir)
        err = os.Setenv("keyTemp", tmpDir)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```

But always (after rerunning the binary) I'm getting the "exists" value as `false` and my env variable is never created!

Comment: What do you mean by always? Are you running the code in a loop? Or are you re-running the binary? If the latter then the answer is obvious, you'd need to persist the env var somehow (~/.bashrc, or ~/.profile, etc..) and reload the env before re-running the binary.

Comment: @mkopriva rerunning the binary

Comment: @mkopriva How can I persist the env var?

Comment: I'm not sure with Windows, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898184/965900) seems to me to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva, it looks no direct way at go lang itself, so the option is to use `cmd`, so it worked with me as:

```golang
tmpDir = os.TempDir() + "\\fitz"
// err = os.Setenv("keyTemp", tmpDir)
err = exec.Command(`SETX`, `keyTemp`, tmpDir).Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
}
```